# Run-time error '424' Object required - Unsure what I've written wrong in this code?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

```
Sub automated_gr_lookup()
    Dim st As Long
    Dim en As Long
    Dim c1 As Long
    Dim c2 As Long
    Dim iRowAsset As Integer
    Dim table As Range
    Dim tmpRiskID As Variant

    Sheets("Geotechnical Risk Register").Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set assetTbl = Application.Range("M002_") 'Asset table = DES M002
    Set riskTbl = Application.Range("geotechRisks") 'GRR
    Set compiledTbl = Application.Range("CompiledM002") 'Output for M002


    For iRowRisk = 1 To riskTbl.Rows.Count 'loop through risks
        tmpRiskID = riskTbl.Row.Range("Ref No. ID") 'Temporary risk as it gets overridden


        'if assets chainage match risk iRowRisk (4 conditions)
        If (en > c1 And en < c2) Or (st > c1 And en < c2) Or (st > c1 And st < c2) Or (st < c1 And en > c2) Then
            'copy asset row
            assetTbl.Rows(iRowAsset).Copy
            'paste row in compiled
            compiledTbl.Rows(xlEndRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            'paste risk id in last column of that row
            compiledTbl.Cells(xlEndRow, ColumnH).Value = tmpRiskID
        End If
    Next iRowRisk

End Sub
```

I'm getting a `runtime error 424` on the line `tmpRiskID = riskTbl.Row.Range("Ref No. ID")` and unsure why? I'm currently trying to assign it to a table heading.

Comment: What is that line supposed to be doing? Assigning a range, a value or a row number to tmpriskid? Whatever it's supposed to be doing the syntax is off.

Comment: `riskTbl.Rows(i)` perhaps instead of `riskTbl.Row` (which returns a row number), but then you can't use `Range("Ref No. ID")` to refer to the heading. I might use `.Cells` here instead of `.Rows`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your prompt response. The line is supposed to store a temporary value (in this case a cell from a Table) and if the condition is met I want it to paste it as followed after the If function.

Comment: But which cell and how does it relate to `irowrisk`? And where do you set the value of those 4 variables in the If line?

Comment: Apologies for my understanding, this is my first code I've written so I'm very noobish when it comes to writing code. BigBen - I tried riskTbl.Rows(i), I didn't get an error but nothing happened, no output. SJR - I guess it doesn't relate to irowrisk now that I think about it? I also haven't set values to the 4 variables - another problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Sheets("Geotechnical Risk Register").Select
> ```

This is where problems begin. Where is this worksheet? If it's in *whatever workbook happens to be active*, then there's run-time error 9 "subscript out of range" waiting to remind you that *whatever workbook happens to be active* may not necessarily have a worksheet by that name.

If the sheet is in the same workbook that hosts your VBA code, then you *don't* want "whatever workbook is currently active", but `ThisWorkbook` - this would already be better:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Geotechnical Risk Register").Select
```

But, you don't *need* to `.Select` anything. Consider:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Geotechnical Risk Register")
```

Much better: now we can make member calls against that specific sheet, and we *know* we're working against the right sheet.

Except, if the sheet exists in `ThisWorkbook` at compile-time, then it's completely redundant.

Select the sheet module in the VBE's *Project Explorer* toolwindow (Ctrl+R), then bring up its *properties* (F4). At the top of the properties list is a `(Name)` property that's currently probably something like `Sheet42` - change that to something more meaningful, say, `GeotechRiskRegisterSheet`. Now you have a global-scope (project-scope, actually) object variable named `GeotechRiskRegisterSheet` that you can use anywhere in your VBA project to refer to *that particular sheet*.

The rest of this answer assumes you've done that. If the sheet isn't in `ThisWorkbook`, then stick to declaring a local `Worksheet` variable for it, and pulling the `Worksheet` object reference from the `Workbook.Worksheets` collection *of the workbook you mean to work with*.

> ```
> Set assetTbl = Application.Range("M002_")
> ```

That's assigning to a variable that appears to want to be a local variable, but isn't declared anywhere in the local scope. `Application.Range` is only slightly better than just `Range`, and only one level of indirection away from the most-explicit `ActiveSheet.Range` - but then again, you *don't* mean to work off *whatever the ActiveSheet is*, and while tables *do* defined named ranges and named ranges *can* be accessed with the `Range` property, this would be much clearer and absolutely unambiguous:

```
Dim assetTbl As ListObject
Set assetTbl = GeotechRiskRegisterSheet.ListObjects("M002_")
```

Same applies to the other two:

> ```
> Set riskTbl = Application.Range("geotechRisks") 'GRR
> Set compiledTbl = Application.Range("CompiledM002") 'Output for M002
> ```

Go with:

```
Dim riskTbl As ListObject
Set riskTbl = GeotechRisksSheet.ListObjects("geotechRisks")

Dim compiledTbl As ListObject
Set compiledTbl = CompiledSheet.ListObjects("CompiledM002")
```

And then we start looping:

> ```
> For iRowRisk = 1 To riskTbl.Rows.Count 'loop through risks
> ```

If `riskTbl` is just another `Range`, then that works. If `riskTbl` is a `ListObject`, we can do simpler & faster:

```
Dim currentRow As ListRow
For Each currentRow In riskTbl.ListRows
```

And then we get to the run-time error you're asking about:

> ```
> tmpRiskID = riskTbl.Row.Range("Ref No. ID") 'Temporary risk as it gets overridden
> ```

That's error 424 "object required", because `riskTbl.Row` is a `Long` integer value: it doesn't have a `Range` member, so you can't do `Range.Row.Range` like this. If you're iterating a plain `Range` with that `For iRowRisk` loop, then you want that to look something like:

```
tmpRiskID = riskTbl.Cells(iRowRisk, 12).Value
```

Where `12` is a hard-coded column index referring to the "Ref No. ID" column. Not ideal, is it? Compare to leveraging the `ListObject` API:

```
Dim refIDColumn As Long
refIDColumn = riskTbl.ListColumns("Ref No. ID").Index

tmpRiskID = currentRow.Range.Cells(ColumnIndex:=refIDColumn).Value
```

If you define the `refIDColumn` variable outside the loop, every iteration can reuse its value, and as long as the header caption remains "Ref No. ID", the column can be anywhere the user wants it - whereas with a hard-coded column index, if the user inserts a new column, the code breaks.

> ```
>     'if assets chainage match risk iRowRisk (4 conditions)
>     If (en > c1 And en < c2) Or (st > c1 And en < c2) Or (st > c1 And st < c2) Or (st < c1 And en > c2) Then
> ```

I'm hoping you have declared and assigned these variables in your actual code - otherwise this conditional expression can't be evaluated reliably, since none of these identifiers have a value. Consider using meaningful names that convey usage intent: `en`, `st`, `c1`, and `c2` mean absolutely nothing to anyone that isn't extremely familiar with the thought process of whoever wrote that code. In any case, make sure the top of the module says `Option Explicit` somewhere.

> ```
>         'copy asset row
>         assetTbl.Rows(iRowAsset).Copy
>         'paste row in compiled
>         compiledTbl.Rows(xlEndRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
>         'paste risk id in last column of that row
>         compiledTbl.Cells(xlEndRow, ColumnH).Value = tmpRiskID
> ```

I'm not convinced you actually need to involve the clipboard here. Again, consider leveraging the `ListObject` API - this should work (untested):

```
    With compiledTbl.ListRows.Add
        .Range.Value = currentRow.Range.Value
        .Range.Cells(ColumnIndex:=compiledRiskIdColumn).Value = tmpRiskID
    End With
```

Where `compiledRiskIdColumn` would be declared and assigned before the loop body:

```
Dim compiledRiskIdColumn As Long
compiledRiskIdColumn = compieldTbl.ListColumns("Risk ID").Index '<~ verify column title
```